# The many artifacts of Vecna

Tags: dnd-3.5e, artifacts

I stumbled across the wikipedia entry for Vecna and [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vecna#Other_artifacts), after going trough a long list of body parts which seams to be all artifacts on their own, says

> These artifacts are collectively known in D&D 3rd Edition as the Fragments of Vecna.

And then continue with some other artifacts :
Compendium Maleficarum (said to be part of the Fragments)
Fragments of Vecna
Tome of Shared Secrets
Rod of the Whispered One
Sword of Kas
Left Ear of Vecna

Aside from the more famous *left hand*, the *(left?) eye* (which I know are both on the DMG) and the *left ear* (Dragon Magazine #359) none have a source.

**Where are described (just cited or with whole effect description)?

Are all found in 3.x edition or some are from the older edition?**

Comment: The page you linked to cites Die Vecna Die! (an AD&D sourcebook) as a source for the other Vecna relics.

Comment: @gaynorvader Yes, but Die Vecna Die! is, as you said, an AD&D book and the text say they are know as Fragments of Vecna in 3rd edition, which suggest that they have been touched again in the 3.x edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of those items can be found in [Dragon #348](http://www.aeolia.net/dragondex/articles-subject.html#v) (see "Vecna" in the index). The [Sword of Kas](http://greyhawkery.blogspot.com/2015/04/sword-of-kas-through-editions.html) is in the 3.0 DMG. The only stats I was able to find for the Compendium Maleficarum were in Die Vecna Die!